# How to create partially populated deeply nested dictionary using LINQ c#

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, dictionary, nested

Need to create deeply nested dictionary that is partially pupulated

```
IDictionary<string, IDictionary<string, IDictionary<DateTime, double>>> AllparamsSmooth
```

I have

```
List<Facility> facilities
```

and

```
List<string> names
```

Need to create AllparamsSmooth where just strings are pupulated^(which are just names) :

Did like this:

```
foreach (var facility in facilities)
{
    AllparamsSmooth.Add(facility.Name, new Dictionary<string, IDictionary<DateTime, double>>()); 

    foreach (var name in names)
    {
      AllparamsSmooth[facility.Name].Add(name, new Dictionary<DateTime, double>());
    }
}
```

Question -how to do this with LINQ

Comment: However you implement this, it's not going to be maintainable unless you redesign.

Comment: Try something like this : var results = facilities.GroupBy(x => facility.Name).ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.GroupBy(n => n.name).ToDictionary(x => x.key, y = y.date));

Comment: var mayNestdictinoary =facilities.GroupBy(x => x.Name).ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => names.ToDictionary(x => x, y => 
(IDictionary<DateTime, double>)new Dictionary<DateTime, double>()));

Comment: tried this but it returns me a collection of key value pairs. Just one Dictionary instead of three nested....

Comment: Did it. Thank you very much for hint!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite ugly and unreadable:

```
AllparamsSmooth = facilities.ToDictionary(
    x => x.Name,
    x => (IDictionary<string, IDictionary<DateTime, double>>)names.ToDictionary(
        y => y,
        y => (IDictionary<DateTime, double>)new Dictionary<DateTime, double>()));
```

Note the various necessary casts, because otherwise you would get a

```
IDictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<DateTime, double>>>
```